# Is is possible to boost some words using StringToWordVector

Tags: weka

I'm using StringToWordVector Naive Bayes and StringToWordVector to classify some text.
I'm also using TD/IDF to put score on words.

Is there a simple way to increase the score of some words (chosen by myself) during the training to increase the weight of this words in the model for a given class?
So if this words are present in a new document the classifier would know there is more chance that the document belongs to this class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to increase the probability that documents containing certain words will be classified as a certain kind of document.

What you can do, is to simply train your classifier with "hand made" documents that contain exactly these words, and then mark these documents as belonging to a specific class.

Comment: I'm already using hand made documents, but I'd like to be able to boost some words with specific weights.
As my example must look like "real world" examples, there are also less important words in them that should have smaller weights